# How to disconnect and reconnect socket.io from client?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, socket.io

I have log messages that are being emitted from server to client and that are coming consistently from server and logging to client, Now I have additional functionality to stop and play logs to give some controls to user, So I am thinking on stop to disconnect `socket.io` connection and on play start `socket.io` connection again, First i am trying with stop to disconnect connection but i could not emit message to server ,any idea what is wrong with below code or any better solution to achieve these task ?
main.html

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="stopLogs()">stop</button>
```

ctrl.js

```
$scope.stopLogs = function(){
        socket.emit('end');
    }
```

angularSOcketFactory.js

```
angular.module('App').factory('socket', function ($rootScope) {
    'use strict';
        var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
        return {
            on: function (eventName, callback) {
                socket.on(eventName, function () {
                    var args = arguments;
                    $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                        callback.apply(socket, args);
                    });
                });
            },
            emit: function (eventName, data, callback) {
                socket.emit(eventName, data, function () {
                    var args = arguments;
                    $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                        if (callback) {
                            callback.apply(socket, args);
                        }
                    });
                })
            }
        };

});
```

server.js

```
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
  io.sockets.on('connection',function(){
   // Producer.startProducer();
    ditconsumer.start(function(value){
        io.emit('ditConsumer',value)
    });
    io.sockets.on('end', function() {
        socket.disconnect();
        console.log('it will disconnet connection');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This code is wrong:

```
io.sockets.on('end',function () {
console.log('this will disconnet socket connection');
 io.sockets.disconnect();
});
```

You need to apply that event listener to one specific socket and then you need to disconnect one specific socket.

You don't show the general context of your server code, but it could be done like this:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.on('end', function() {
        socket.disconnect();
    });
});
```

You could also just have the client disconnect directly rather than asking the server to do it for you.

Comment: I updated my question for better understanding from server side but issue here is its not even emitting message from client side when i click on `stopLogs()` method.

Comment: @hussain - Well, your server code is still wrong and needs correcting.  `io.sockets.on(...)` is wrong and should be `socket.on(...)`.  I don't know angular so I'll leave that for someone else if there actually is an issue there.

Comment: `socket.on('end')` is throwing exception socket is not defined i tried with `io.on('end')` same result.

Comment: @hussain - Look at my recommend code very closely.  You probably aren't declaring the socket parameter to the event handler like the code in my answer has.  See where I have `function(socket)` in my answer.  This is how you get the `socket` of the new connection and that's what you should be operating on.

Comment: can i do `socket.connect()` to reconnect connection again ?

Comment: @hussain - Only the client can reconnect.  Servers can't connect directly to browser clients.  Browsers connect to servers.

Comment: disconnect is working with your example , Can you provide answer for client re-connect it will resolve my question.

Comment: @hussain - It's not obvious to me what you're trying to do here in the client.  You can just create a new connection by just repeating your client socket setup code: `var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');` and then the other initialization code on that new `socket`.

Comment: Thanks that helps me to understand!